# Why did phenol respond to Brady's reagent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, phenols

I was teaching a friend a few basic organic analysis experiments, during which I was showing him, how to get an alcohol, and took a sample of phenol.

The neutral $\ce{FeCl3}$ test went fine(which i mentioned, was only for phenols), with an ultra dark violet colouration, but just to show him a negative test, i added some of Brady's reagent, and surprisingly, it gave a yellowish colouration (something close, a mix of yellow and orange, couldn't trust my eyes, since i was kind of in disbelief). The samples in the lab are mostly pure, and not mixtures of different organic compounds. To satisfy him, i gave a possible explanation, saying that the phenol might've got oxidised to hydroquinone, and hence, might've given the test.

What probably would've happened there? Any chances my explanation was right?

Comment: Reagent has color by itself there needs to be precipitate.

Comment: Im not sure,  just saw the solution turn yellowish, didnt check for a precipitate.  Probably thats why it happened @Mithoron